# Etw kernel consume events

Tags: callback, windows-vista, kernel, etw

I am wondering if it is at all possible to receive etw events (vista+) using kernel code?  I saw an example using user-mode functions, but I don't see any examples using kernel-mode functions.  I understand that drivers are more commonly the providers, but I figure that the ability should still be there in kernel-mode to consume these events in a callback.

If anyone has any experience, I'd appreciate hearing about it.  Thanks.
Jeff